# jackson - jackson parser not parsing the json

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I have written a small web service and I am passing a JSON. On sending the request RESTClient says : `Status Code: 415 Unsupported Media Type`, thought I have put the header Content-Type: application/json.

The error message I am receiving on the server side is :

```
    [ERROR   ] A message body reader for Java class com.udm.jsons.JSON_Device, and Java type class com.udm.jsons.JSON_Device, and MIME media type application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json; charset=UTF-8 ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
```

I have used the correct format on the server side alse :

```
@Path("/initiateProvisioning")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseInfo initiateProvisioning(JSON_Device device)
```

And I have generated the POJO for jackson use use jsonschema2pojo.org.Please help, I have been stuck for quiet  !!!

Comment: 1) Add this Maven dependency `com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:${version}` 2) [Configure](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#json.pojo.approach.section) 3) Report results

Comment: And why are you tagging Jersey 2?  The error infers you are using Jersey 1.

Comment: I am not using Maven and ya sorry I will change the tag

Comment: Do you know how to use Maven and do you have access to it? If so, create new Maven project and add that dependency, then see everything it pulls in. Copy them to your project

Answer (score 0):

Without the full request sent to the REST service, I can only make suppositions. Check if the header and the payload is UTF-8 encoded. Also, the payload must only be something like {...}

Comment: i validated the payload from jsonlint.com , payload is correct, but how to encode it in UTF-8, can you please explain

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, you are posting JSON payload from the client and trying to receive it in the form of a POJO in one of your resource methods. You need a MessageBodyReader to achieve this. An implementation of this interface will contain the logic to convert your raw (JSON) input stream to a POJO (JSON_Device). JAX-RS run time will automatically invoke this when it's about to invoke your method and inject the returned object into your method (initiateProvisioning) parameter

JAX-RS javadocs - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html